# How do I save combo-box values to a SharePoint list?

Tags: excel, powerapps, sharepoint-list

I have a Power App where users input a serial number. I have 1 text-box and 3 combo-boxes that depend on the serial number input by the user. The lookup table is in Excel. It is working and able to do lookup.

However, I need to be able to record the data in a SharePoint list. The text-box is recorded properly, but the values of the combo-boxes are not.

In short... Power App > User input serial > Lookup excel table for 4 attributes of the serial > user clicks submit in the power app > power app records data in Sharepoint list > power automate flow sends email notification.

Comment: Have you tried displaying the results of the lookup into a simple Label control first to see if it actually returns something? To rule out that its not a control issue. If nothing appears in the label, that means its something to do with the Excel spreadsheet itself. Is the Excel table defined?

Comment: also, have you checked if your data types match? The values from Excel could conflict with what SharePoint expects. Use the Monitor functionality to see what is being sent to SharePoint by your app and what is the response coming from SharePoint.

Comment: Hello @thebernardlim thank you for your comment. i have not tried displaying the result in a label but that would be useful... thank you very much!

Comment: hello @mmikesy90 you are right! the column in the sharepoint is a choice column whereas i have been doing lookup in the powerapp and excel backend for a single line of text type of field. thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Use Patch function like this

Patch('DataSouceName', Defaults('DataSouceName'), {Title: TextInput1.Text, Comboboxfield: {Value: Combobox1.Selected.Value}})

Here, **Combobox1** is the name of the combo box and **Comboboxfield** is the name of the column where you need to store the combo box selected value.

For more info on Power Apps visit the following website:
http://ashishcoder.com/courses/power-apps/topics-list.html

Thank you